# How to bind data in heredoc of scala?

Tags: scala, heredoc, rawstring

```
val name = "mike"
val str = """Hi, {name}!"""
println(str)
```

I want it output the str as `Hi, mike!`, but failed. How to do this?

Comment: `val str = "Hi, " + name + "!"` ?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183503/substitute-values-in-a-string-with-placeholders-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala does not support string interpolation. There is a compiler plugin that implements it at http://github.com/jrudolph/scala-enhanced-strings.

Without the plugin you can use concatenation or format strings:

```
val str = name formatted "Hi, %s!"
```

or of course

```
val str = "Hi, %s!".format(name)
```

Comment: @Moritz, thank you for your answer. I don't understand why scala not support it heredoc, since they support it in xml

Comment: @Freewind in XML literals the curly braces are actually just a fancy syntax for inserting an instance of scala.xml.Text with the string value of the block into the XML nodes. XML is a bit special here but Strings are just Strings to the compiler.

Comment: @Freewind Also see this discussion on why Scala doesn't support string interpolation: http://goo.gl/cJ5u

Comment: You can also make `format` more Pythonic with an implicit: http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2010/06/fun-with-scala-implicits/

Comment: @Rahuλ G, I can't open the http://goo.gl/cJ5u, but I want to see it much. Can you open it ?

Comment: @Freewind, Yes, I am able to open it. You can try this direct link if the shortened URL isn't working: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Why-Martin-hates-string-interpolation-Was-Re-Formatting-Questions-Summary-td2008748.html

Comment: @Rahuλ G, it's very interesting. Is really because of keyboard?

Comment: @Freewind, As he himself clarified in the discussion, Odersky uses a US keyboard. So this Swiss keyboard theory is obviously wrong. :)

Comment: @Rahuλ, yes :) So, the true reason is a secret

Comment: This is outdated! String interpolation exists in scala, refer to @javabda's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23875645/5214346

Answer (score 5):

A total hackish solution would be to use Scala's XML interpolation:

```
val name = "Mike"
val str = <a>Hi, {name}!</a> text
```

The `text` method returns string contents of an XML construct, so our tags are stripped.

Comment: +1  This is basically a "canonical" hack. Maybe being so accepted (and useful) this is not really a "hack" anymore??

Answer (score 4):

As of scala >= 2.10 string interpolations are supported:

```
val str = "Foo Bar"
str: String = Foo Bar

scala> s"Interpolating: $str"
res0: String = Interpolating: Foo Bar
```